# Google+-Package name not getting added to String[]?

Tags: android, string, sharedpreferences

My app is keeping a "third-party app-exclude-list" as package names in a `String[]` (and serializing it to the `SharedPreferences` using the method below). This works fine, but for some users, the Google+ isn't getting added to this list. It *only* happens for the Google+ app. For all I know, the G+ app isn't anything special, it's package name on Google Play is listed as `com.google.android.apps.plus`, which shouldn't confuse the saving-algorithm. It works fine on my own phone, so I'm stumped at what causes this, but a lot of my users have reported this as an issue :-/!

```
public void saveExcludedApplicationList(String[] applicationList) {
    mExcludedApplicationList = applicationList;
    String combined = "";
    for (int i=0; i<mExcludedApplicationList.length; i++){
        combined = combined + mExcludedApplicationList[i] + ";";
    }
    mPref.edit().putString(PREF_EXCLUDED_APPLICATION_LIST, combined).commit();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this had nothing to do with the way I was serializing this, but with the "Google+ Messaging" app beging distributed as the same package as G+.

Comment: How did you solve this issue? By the looks of it, when you get the list of applications on the phone using List<PackageInfo> apps=getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA|PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS|PackageManager.GET_PROVIDERS); , the google+ package is not included in the return list since it has the same packagename. So how did you fix it to include google+ also?