# How to retrieve multiple applications with same Package Name in Android?

Tags: android, android-package-managers

I am using the following code to retrieve the list of installed applications on the phone:

```
List<PackageInfo> apps=getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA|PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS|PackageManager.GET_PROVIDERS);
```

But if there are two applications with same package name, only one of them are returned. How to get both the application details in the list? I am facing this issue with the **Google+** app, which has the same package name **com.google.android.apps.plus** as another app , and hence is not returned.

Comment: `How to retrieve multiple applications with same Package Name in Android` I am sure this is the funniest question ever for Android. Device can not have more than one application with same package name.

Comment: It is funny but true. I built my entire application on the assumption that package name is unique, but *only* for this application, it fails. Please see for yourself in this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18160557/google-package-name-not-getting-added-to-string ..my problem is the same

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the AndroidManifest documentation here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html, It is clear that the package name is a unique identifier for an application.

If two applications have the same package name, only one of them will be installed.  If they share the same signature, installing the second package will overwrite the first assuming it doesn't downgrade the version. If they have different signatures, you'll get an error saying that you can't install the second package.

That said, you should never be in a situation where you have two packages with the same name installed on your device.

Comment: Please see for yourself in this link, my problem is the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18160557/google-package-name-not-getting-added-to-string

Comment: Wow, this must be possible then for packages that get installed with the platform.  I'm really surprised Google would do this.

Comment: This is a one in a million chance. I was flabbergasted by it :) But there is nothing I can do since this is the standard way of getting list of installed applications